# How To Upload Log.txt File

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, upload, ftp

I am searching a free service which allow there users to upload files in there account programmatically. Actually I want to upload a log.txt file which contains errors strings which occurs in my application which is running in client computer. I know we can use Email service to send logs or strings but I don't want to use email, I am searching FTP or HTTP upload.

Comment: So you're not looking for how to do it programmatically?  You're just looking for ideas of some services out there that provide that functionality?  If that's the case, I would think almost any ISP would offer FTP, SFTP, or FTPS access.

Comment: I am looking for the Service that provide upload functionality from your desktop programmatically. I'm not looking for CODES. Do you know about "ERROR REPORTING" "SEND ERROR REPORT" in many programs. @StevenDoggart

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx